# Recorded H.264 video from Android is not playable from video tag in Chrome and black screen in Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, html5-video, mp4, android-mediarecorder

I'm developing Android app to record video and see it from web page.

I've used MediaRecorder and it works well and I can play it from VLC player but not playable from web page. ( Not playable from Chrome, only audio with black screen from Safari )

Recorded video file : https://journalone.blob.core.windows.net/teacher111/1465525259622fileVID_20160610_121918.mp4

Is MediaRecorder from Android has some problem?

Answer (score 0):

That file is 3GP despite the .mp4 file extension. Check you are setting the [output format](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOutputFormat(int)).

Comment: Yeah, I set profile from camera to mediaRecorder and output format is 3gp from camera. But it still not working even if I change output format to MPEG-4 or change output file extension to .3gp

Comment: 3gp file : https://journalone.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/VID_20160613_215409.3gp

- output format to mp4 : https://journalone.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/VID_20160613_221751.mp4

Comment: That "mp4" is also 3gp, if you inspect it with ffprobe or mediainfo.